# Why is a method of a interface not found by C# dynamic on internal classes?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I tried to use `dynamic` to access methods of classes that are located in another assembly. These classes are `internal` and created by builders that return a `public` interface. For some reason `dynamic` is not able to invoke the method defined on the interface. I can use "classic" reflection to get the code running but I don't understand why it's not working with `dynamic`.

I know that `dynamic` is not working with methods of internal classes but here we have a public interface. So please can someone explain why `dynamic` throws the `RuntimeBinderException` in the example below?

```cs
    namespace SandboxLib  // located in SandboxLib.dll
    {
        public class InternalBuilder
        {
            public static IInterface Build()
            {
                return new InternalClass();
            }
        }

        public interface IInterface
        {
            void IfMethod();
        }
        
        internal class InternalClass : IInterface
        {
            public void IfMethod() { }
        }
    }

    namespace Sandbox  // located in Sandbox.dll
    {
        public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var inst = InternalBuilder.Build();
                dynamic dynInst = inst;

                inst.IfMethod();     // ok
                dynInst.IfMethod();  // Unhandled exception. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'IfMethod'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seemingly doesn't care about the interface, and is trying to access the instantiated internal class methods. I would have to wonder why you are in situation to start with. `dynamic` *anything* usually causes 2 more problems than it solves on the best of days

Comment: The application is a simple inspection tool to show values provided by the internal classes. Since this classes are generic classes and the methods are ```async``` methods, using reflection is a bit of a pain. At the given location I don't know what generic type the internal class has and therefor a lot of code is needed to extract the value. But you're right, usually I try to avoid using ```dynamic``` and prefer explicit types where ever possible.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this is situation is not permitted, reflection maybe your only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is described in the C# Standard:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#dynamic-binding

Under "Member Lookup" it states:

> Member lookup considers not only the name of a member but also the
> number of type parameters the member has and **whether the member is
> accessible**.

Since the member `IfMethod()` that the `dynamic` resolution has found is `internal`, the call will fail, as per the specification.

Comment: But it seems a bit limited that it doesn't look up interface members. At compile time it resolves correctly to the interface, why doesn't it do the same at runtime?

Comment: @InBetween Well, that would be a question to be addressed to the language designers, but the spec is quite clear about it.

Comment: I guess you could also take a look at **12.3 Static and Dynamic Binding** of the ecma specs “*However, if an expression is a dynamic expression (i.e., has the type dynamic) this indicates that any binding that it participates in should be based on its run-time type rather than the type it has at compiletime. The binding of such an operation is therefore deferred until the time where the operation is to be executed during the running of the program. This is referred to as dynamic binding.*“

Comment: I still don't see this as a valid reason. You are telling me that *dynamic* essentially invalidates polymorphism through interfaces... that doesn't make much sense. I've built a simple example where *dynamic* binds perfectly well to an interface exposing an unreachable type. Check [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZDXsL6). Its not the same, but this should also fail if your reasoning were correct or maye I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: @InBetween yeah that's not the same, your base type actually supports the method and it's accessable

Comment: @MichaelRandall why? In the context of this answer, its an unreachable member exposed through an interface. Why should one bind and the other not? In my example the dynamic binding binds correctly to the interface member `IFoo.Frob` which should be the expected behavior (anything else seems extremely bewildering to me), not `Foo.FooA.Frob`. Why doesn't it do the same in the OP's code? Has anyone checked if the issue is reproducible btw? I can't at this moment.

Comment: @InBetween You have definitely found an interesting exception to what the specs are saying. Though, I'd have to dig more to prove why, though I'm on my phone

Comment: @MichaelRandall ah you are right! its binding to `Foo.Frob`, not `IFoo.Frob`. [This](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y7aYJe) actually fails too, which is the exact same scenario as the OP. Wow, had no idea about this, I find it an extremely unexpected limitation of *dynamic*.